# How to handle dependencies with CMake

Tags: qt, cmake, qmake

I'm trying to convert my previous qmake approach to cmake. I have a static lib called shared that links with different applications as a common ground. Each application has it's own static lib called common to link with the different targets of the same application (standalone, plugin-format-1, plugin-format-2, etc).

```
shared/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── shared.cmake
│   .

project/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── common/
├── common/CMakeLists.txt
│   common/common.cmake
│   .
```

When I'm developing and debbuging I want to avoid the hassle of compiling each lib individually so in debug mode I would usually include shared.pri and common.pri and when compiling the application, everything would compile smoothly, all toghether. I'm trying to replicate this include pattern using .cmake files.

```
#project.pro

include(../shared/shared.pri)
include(common/common.pri)
```

When I want to make a final and release version of the application I have a build script that compile the shared static lib, the common static lib and then links the different targets with this libs.

I have already created the CMakeLists.txt for the shared and common static libs. My problem now is how to replicate the pattern described above with cmake because when including the shared.cmake and common.cmake in the application CMakeLists.txt, the paths are not compatible. It seems that when you include(xxx.cmake), the path will always be relative to the parent CMakeLists.txt.

What would be the right way of achieving this with CMake? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `add_subdirectory()` instead of include.  For `shared`, which is "out-of-tree", you'll also need to specify the binary directory (the place to put the generated and compiled files).

```
add_subdirectory(../shared shared)
add_subdirectory(common)
```

Any targets created in those subprojects will now be available for you to link with `target_link_libraries` in your main project.

When you build your separate versions, consider using `export()` and/or `install(EXPORT)` to produce cmake files that you can include from your application projects *instead* of using `add_subdirectory()`, so that can be the only change you need to make.

Comment: Why the inconsistent case used with cmake commands? Imho all cmake commands should be lowercase to match the documentation, even though command names are case insensitive...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One problem I'm having with this approach is the fact that the include_directories and defines that are already defined in shared and common are not being added to the project where I'm including them which means that I need to repeat those includes. Is this supposed to happen or am I missing something?

Comment: You need to use `target_include_directories()` and `target_compile_definitions()` at the site where you create those targets, so that they are attached to the targets themselves, and and will be applied transitively to anything you link them to.  Use those *instead* of the old-style `include_directories()` and similar.

Comment: Curiosily, I have read about that and tried to use target_include_directories() but I was not getting any success. I might be doing anything else wrong.